# Timing issue with loading css/defining javascript variables

Tags: javascript, php, css

I'm having an issue with timing of scripts being loaded and variables being defined.  I load up my CSS using Minify, then define the javascript variable window.myQtipFontAdjustmentStyle which is a class from my main.css script (for example, window.myQtipFontAdjustmentStyle = 'qtipFont_125').  That style is then to be used in qtip_help_format.js which is loaded last (in theory!).  What I'm finding is that if I define the qtipFont_125 style in the script, the correct css is used in the qtip_help_format.js.  However, if I load it externally (as below), then the class doesn't seem to be defined "fast enough" for the qtip_help_format.js to have access to it.  While I *could* use `<style>.qtipFont_125 { stylestuff }</style>` within the script, it certainly would be better to load it with the rest of my CSS.  Any suggestions or thoughts would be appreciated.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/min/f=css/main.css,jquery/qtip/jquery.qtip.min.css" /><script type="text/javascript">

    <?php if ($auth->hasIdentity()) {?>
    window.myQtipFontAdjustmentStyle = 'qtipFont_<?php echo ($identity->font_multiplier)*100;?>';
    <?php } else { ?>
    window.myQtipFontAdjustmentStyle = 'qtipFont_100';
    <?php } ?>

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/min/f=jquery/jquery_1.7.2/jquery_1.7.2.js,jquery/qtip_help_format.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why don't you write the style to an inline css block?

Comment: That's what I was trying to get at with my "I could use <style>.qtipFont_125 {stylestuff}</style>" as described above.  And, this solution does work.  However, it would be great if I could keep it in my external file.